# decent way of nested definition in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, mit-scheme, guile

I want to define a constant `foo` using an auxiliary function, say, `bar`. And I want to hide `bar` inside the definition of `foo`, so I come with this code:

```
(define foo
  (define (bar n)
    (+ n n))
  (bar 1))
```

However, this definition causes syntax errors in many scheme implementations(mit-scheme, racket, guile, etc.).

I have three workarounds but none of them seems satisfactory:

```
(define foo1
  ((lambda ()
     (define (bar n)
       (+ n n))
     (bar 1))))

(define foo2
  (let ((bar (lambda (n) (+ n n))))
    (bar 1)))

(define (foo3)
  (define (bar n)
    (+ n n))
  (bar 1))
```

`foo1` uses lambda to create an environment of writing auxiliary definitions and the parentheses seem somehow confusing.

`foo2` uses let expression but I can no longer use the syntactic sugar `(define (f n) ...)` => `(define f (lambda (n) ...))`

`foo3` requires less modification comparing with the original one, but every time I want this value, I have to call `(foo3)` and do the computation all over again.

My questions are:

1. I think this kind of nested definition makes sense, but why it is considered a syntax error?
2. is there any decent way to write the definition of `foo`?

Comment: Both `foo1` and `foo2` are equivalent (`let` uses `lambda` under the hood). On the other hand, `foo3` is defining a new function, not a constant value as the other options, so it's not equivalent.

Comment: the standard and correct way to rewrite nested `define`s (which *are* recursive) is with `letrec`: `(define foo (letrec ((bar (lambda(n) (+ n n)))) (bar 1)))`. which is equivalent to the (more popular) *"named `let`"* construct, `(define foo (let bar ((n 1)) (+ n n)))` (even though `bar` isn't called recursively here at all).

Comment: (define foo1
  ((lambda ()
     (define (bar n)
       (+ n n))
     (bar 1)))), this has excess of parenthesis, remove one pair of parenthesis around the lambda; like this (define foo1
  (lambda ()
     (define (bar n)
       (+ n n))
     (bar 1))). It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. `define` can only be used in certain ways, as mandated by the [specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_352). What you want to do isn't covered by the specification, hence the error. As you know, `define` assigns a name to the value of an expression, it's just that you can't directly create internal definitions in its context.
2. But there are other expressions that allow creating new bindings in this context. IMHO `foo2` is the best option here, and it's idiomatic, too. And if `bar` were a recursive definition, you could use `letrec`.

But if loosing a bit of syntactic sugar bothers you (because of the way procedures are defined inside a `let` expression), then try using [`local`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html), it'll work in Racket:

```
(define foo
  (local [(define (bar n) (+ n n))]
    (bar 1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, another idiomatic way to do this in Racket would be to use a module.

This module could be defined using a separate file:

```
;; foo.rkt
#lang racket
(define (bar n)
  (+ n n))
(define foo (bar 1))
(provide foo)

;; use-foo.rkt
#lang racket
(require "foo.rkt")
foo
```

Or via a `module` form within one file:

```
#lang racket
(module 'foo-mod racket
  (define (bar n)
    (+ n n))
  (define foo (bar 1))
  (provide foo))

(require 'foo-mod)
foo
```

Is this concise compared to your examples? Of course not. But in practice this sort of encapsulation usually works fine at a module granularity.

- For instance a private helper like `bar` might be useful in defining multiple other functions or constants.
- Often the file form is more convenient: If a helper like `bar` is *not* nested, but instead at the module top level for `foo.rkt`, it's easier to debug it in a REPL.

p.s. Racket provides a `define-package` form for compatibility with Chez Scheme, but it's not idiomatic in Racket; instead you'd use a submodule.

Answer (score 4):

Your original code has a syntax error because the required syntax for `define` of an identifier is

```
(define <identifier> <expression>)
```

but your syntax is

```
(define <identifier> <definition> <expression>)
```

You need some way to group the `<definition>` and the `<expression>`.  What you are looking for is something that allows lexical definitions - in Scheme this is a syntactic form with a `<body>`.  The syntactic forms for this are a `lambda` or any `let` (and variants) or a 'programmatic' `begin`.

But, this is easily done in Scheme w/o needing Racket extensions or extra, empty lexical environments or a `<body>` syntactic form.  Just use what you considered 'unsatisfactory'

```
(define foo
  (let ((bar (lambda (x) (+ x x))))
    (bar 1)))
```

or even

```
(define foo
  ((lambda (x) (+ x x)) 1))
```

Too much sugar, even syntactic sugar, my have adverse health consequences...

Comment: "Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon." Alan J. Perlis, epigram 3. http://www.cs.yale.edu/quotes.html

Answer (score 3):

`foo1` is also equivalent to the following:

```
(define foo1
  (let ()
    (define (bar n)
      (+ n n))
    (bar 1)))
```

Is that more acceptable-looking to you?