# Internal Definitions in Block Structure

Tags: scheme, sicp

```
(define (sqrt x)
  (define (good-enough? guess x)
    (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
  (define (improve guess x)
    (average guess (/ x guess)))
  (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around around internal block structure. If the syntax for define is: (define *procedure arg arg* body). How are you able to define all the other local-scope variables inside the top-level define?

Is there a syntax exception for defines?

Comment: It would be useful to know which Scheme you're using. Also, you may want to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896471/decent-way-of-nested-definition-in-scheme) and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `define` is not `(define procedure arg .. body)`. It is either `(define (name . args) defines ... body1 bodyn ...)` which is a shortcut for `(define name (lambda args defines ... body1 bodyn ...))`. Note that `x ...` means zero or more so `(lambda (a b) (+ a b))` is fine but `(lambda (a b) (define (test) (+ a b)))` isn't.

Internal `define` is handled by the `lambda` syntax. Basically it gets rewritten to a `letrec`. So

```
(define (sqrt x)
  (define (good-enough? guess x)
    (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
  (define (improve guess x)
    (average guess (/ x guess)))
  (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

Becomes:

```
(define sqrt
  (lambda (x)
    (letrec ((good-enough? (lambda (guess x)
                             (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001)))

             (improve (lambda (guess x)
                        (average guess (/ x guess))))
             (sqrt-iter (lambda (guess x)
                          (if (good-enough? guess x)
                              guess
                              (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))))
      (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))))
```

Obviously the reason for using local `define` is to keep it flatter and more readable than `letrec`. Keeping the same name even though they are totally different beasts that are handled by different parts of the implementation is a simplification for scheme programmers but harder to grasp and understand if you try to figure out how scheme implementations work.

Comment: In R6RS and R7RS, internal definitions by 'define' are rewritten as letrec*, not letrec.  A later definition can evaluate an earlier one.